# How to reference converter in a ResourceDictionary file

Tags: forms, xamarin, resourcedictionary

I'm trying to create a resource dictionary file and reference a Value Converter. How can this be done?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:CS.Runtime.Crew.Converters"               
x:Class="CS.Runtime.Crew.Resources.CrewResourceDictionary" >

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <!--<converters:DateTimeToNullableDateTimeConverter x:Key="DateTimeToNullableDateTimeConverter" />-->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<DataTemplate x:Key="workGroupAttributesTemplate">
    <Grid>
<controls:ExtendedDatePicker NullableDate="{Binding Attributes[DueDate], Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToNullableDateTimeConverter}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you add the `class` namespace

We assume *class is Checker* and *checker is the namespace*

**Header**

```
xmlns:checker="clr-namespace:Something.Checker;assembly=Something
```

**Body**

```
<checker:MySpecialValueConverter x:Key="MySpecialValue"/>
```

You can read more here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#the-ivalueconverter-interface